# CLion не видит qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, clion, cmakelists

Я вроде бы подключил qt5 в CMakeLists.txt но вылетает ошибка:

```
fatal error: 'QGuiApplication' file not found
#include <QGuiApplication>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -static -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi -v")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(Qt5_DIR "/usr/include/qt/")

add_executable(project ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(project /usr/include/qt/Qt5Widgets.a /usr/include/qt/Qt5Gui.a /usr/include/qt/Qt5Core.a /usr/include/qt/QtQml.a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а где include_directories к библиотекам Qt? Про отличие #include "..." от #include <...> не забывайте...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake